# Creating an Array for the first time

Tags: java

My assignment is : Create a Class to store 100 integers in an Array.  Call your class “SimpleArray”, and store it in a file called “SimpleArray.java”.  All code should go in the main() method.  First declare an array of 100 integers.  Use a for loop to store the numbers between 500 and 599 in the array.  Then build a second loop to print out the data in this array.

This is what I have.

```
public class SimpleArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = new int[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            myArray[i] = i + 1;
        }   

        for (int y = 500; y < 599; y++) {
            System.out.println(myArray[y]);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated I don't quite understand how to do the two different loops. My program works, but it doesn't do what my assignment asks for it to do.

Comment: Why would your 100 element array suddenly have indexes 500 to 598? 1. Have a look at the values you are setting in your array - they are not what is asked for. 2. Have a look at how you are printing the array. It is totally wrong.

Comment: Well, i'm confused if I am suppose to keep the index from 500 to 599 for each loop. Because it says to store it in a 0 to 100 loop.

Comment: Don't mix index with values. The indexes will remain the same over the whole lifetime, always starting at 0. The values, stored at these indexes, can vary.

Comment: @HaleyNewbold inxdexes and the data stored at each index are different concepts. That is probably the point of the homework. Ignore all the well meaning answers that just give you the code. Make sure you understand what they are doing.

Comment: Here's a hint: both loops should be `for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)`, but the first loop should manipulate the `i` value when you *set the value*. Indices and values are distinct!

Comment: @John3136 ok thank you. This is all new to me, I'm just trying to understand everything.. Thanks! :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: You got it wrong :). You don't manipulate the i-value, but the myArray[i] value.

Comment: @userunknown I guess it's an issue of semantics, but, the hint is: you'll have to do something with `i` before you assign it to the array element... something *very similar* to what the OP is already doing...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Yes, but not to manipulate the i, else your loop will be broken.

Comment: @userunknown ah, yes, I see what you are getting it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one. This may help u

```
public class SimpleArray  {

        public static void main(String args[]) {

            int[] myArray = new int[100];

            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                myArray[i] = i + 500;
            }   

            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(myArray[i]);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: How about using the simplified for-loop for printing?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly to store the numbers

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = i + 500;  // store [0] = 0 + 500, [1] = 1 + 500 etc
}
```

and then to print

```
for (int y = 0; y < myArray.length; y++)
        System.out.println(myArray[y]);
}
```

There is also an easier way to print the entire array

```
    for (int val : myArray) {
        System.out.println(val);
    }
```

Comment: @userunknown any reason to confuse the OP any more than necessary?

Comment: Yes, the same reason they were invented for: Security, immunity to bounds changing in the source. Usage to the more secure way to do things.

Comment: @userunknown this is a user in an introductory programming class. They should stick to basic concepts first.

Comment: @userunknown Edited, but if the OP's tutor ask him to only print a range, he would again be stuck

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Security is a basic concept.

Comment: @ScaryWombat: If and when. And if the array is resized to 10 or 1000, the loop has to be visited again. And therefore it is a bad concept, to iterate by hand. You should learn to avoid it as soon as possible.

Comment: @userunknown actually, I would say basic flow control is even more basic than security. But anyway, I mostly code in a language which doesn't even *have* C-style loops, only for-each loops...

Comment: @userunknown I agree with you, you only have to stick around SO for a day to see how many OOB Exceptions are posted about, and the fact that most of the answers posted in this question are wrong

Answer (score 0):

The learning material your teacher uses is outdated.

> Create a Class to store 100 integers in an Array. Call your class
>   “SimpleArray”, and store it in a file called “SimpleArray.java”. All
>   code should go in the main() method. First declare an array of 100
>   integers.

So far you did well.

The modern way to fill an array is with range/toArray:

```
int[] myArray = IntStream.range (0, 100).toArray ();
```

It's more robust against off-by-one-errors, which Programmers are known for. And it follows the good practice RAII: Resource allocation is initialization.

However, it was never said, to fill the Array with values from 0 to 99.

> Use a for loop to store the numbers between 500 and 599 in
>   the array.

Ok, for setting the values to a new value, based on the old one, there is some innovation too, mostly unknown to elder programmers, which stick to outdated concepts (if the job has been, to initialize them to 0..99):

```
Arrays.setAll (myArray, i ->  myArray[i] + 500);
```

That's elegant, isn't it? And it is size agnostic, that means, if you decide, to change your array to `new int [200]` or 50, you wouldn't need to touch this code. Well, but the exercise says: "Use a for loop to store the numbers between 500 and 599 in the array." so you can't use it, but you may ask your teacher, which Java version you're teached for - Java-1.4, maybe?

Here is an alternative approach, if the array is initialized to 100 zeros, which is the default for:

```
int[] myArray = new int[100]; // 100 Zeros

IntStream.range (0, 100).forEach (i -> myArray[i] = i + 500);
```

Or

```
IntStream.range (500, 600).forEach (i -> myArray[i-500] = i);
```

or better:

```
IntStream.range (0, myArray.length).forEach (i -> myArray[i] = i + 500);
IntStream.range (500, 500 + myArray.length).forEach (i -> myArray[i-500] = i);
```

To react flexible on array size changes.

> Then build a second loop to print out the data in this array.

For output, you might use the simplified for-loop, being around over a decade, and still not adapted by the masses:

```
for (int i : myArray) 
    System.out.print (" " + i ); 

500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 520 521 522 523 524 525 526 527 528 529 530 531 532 533 534 535 536 537 538 539 540 541 542 543 544 545 546 547 548 549 550 551 552 553 554 555 556 557 558 559 560 561 562 563 564 565 566 567 568 569 570 571 572 573 574 575 576 577 578 579 580 581 582 583 584 585 586 587 588 589 590 591 592 593 594 595 596 597 598
```

This is probably not appropriate for a beginner, either, but answer should be general answers, for people with the same question, how to initialize an Array, how to manipulate it, how to do output.

And that's the modern style of Java8, afaik. So people, switching from other, modern languages to Java, they might feel better served with this answer, which might be similar to what they know from their languages.

Critical for beginners is often, to not confuse the index of the Array with the value, stored at that index.

Since there are Arrays for Strings, for Doubles, for JButtons and everything, you can imagine, starting with something else than ints would be didactically more useful.

Comment: Thank you so much, for taking time to write this out. I appreciate your help greatly!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 int[] myArray = new int[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = i + 500;
    }   

    for (int y = 0; y < myArray.length; y++) {
        System.out.println(myArray[y]);
    }
```

Comment: And again, where is the simplified for-loop for printing?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SimpleArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = new int[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            myArray[i] = i + 500;
        }   

        for (int y = 0; y < myArray.length; y++) {
            System.out.println(myArray[y]);
        }
    }
}
```

System.out.println(myArray[y]) , here y refer to index not to value. 
so there is no index for 500 +, only 100 indexes which start from 0 and end with 99.

Comment: er `0 + 501` does not equal `500`

Comment: I Just try to make understand you what happening behind the code and the mistake you have done. dont worry about values. you just have to modify them.

Comment: @ChamlyIdunil thanks, Im a the array value stuff is kinda confusing me right now, but hopefully it will make sense soon!

Comment: myArray[i] = i + 500; here myArray[i] means index of array. when value inside []means index of array. value contain after equal mark. here ( myArray[i] = i + 500 ) i + 500 is value. here what we do we set value equal to index i+ 500 to index i. Its really easy to understand. just try fill and print values of index.